# Function Lists Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out this problem on Codecademy, but I can not figure it out.
Ok so I need to make this so it will return the number of times a word is said in a list.

Here is what it says to do:

> Write a function that counts how many times the string "fizz" appears
>   in a list.
>
> 1.Write a function called fizz_count that takes a list x as input.
>
> 2.Create a variable count to hold the ongoing count. Initialize it to
>   zero.
>
> 3.for each item in x:, if that item is equal to the string "fizz"
>   then increment the count variable.
>
> 4.After the loop, please return the
>   count variable.
>
> For example, fizz_count(["fizz","cat","fizz"]) should
>   return 2.

Then here is what I have written:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == "fizz":
            count = count + 1
            return count
```

To look at this lesson the number is **A Day at the Supermarket 4/13**

Comment: Just for completeness:  In Python you have the method `.count()` on lists, so your function could return just `x.count('fizz')`.  Also, instead of `count = count + 1` you can use `count += 1`.  This is shorted and avoids doubling the code for the lvalue (`count`) in the idiom.

Answer (score 8):

You're so close! You've just got the indentation wrong.

#### What you have:

```
for item in x:
    if item == 'fizz':
        count = count + 1
        return count # Returns any time we hit "fizz"!
```

#### What you need:

```
for item in x:
    if item == 'fizz':
        count += 1  # how we normally write this
return count   # after the loop, at the base indent level of the function
```

Answer (score 4):

You're returning `count` inside your `for` loop; you should finish iterating over your list, and then return.

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there. The indentation is wrong. Your code should be:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == "fizz":
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Comment: TY IT WORKED!! :D Could I also do this with like "Count += 1"?

Comment: Yes, this will also work. Without the capital though: `count += 1`

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that when a `return` statement is reached, the function will be exited. What you should do instead is to *return* the count after the `for` loop ends:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == "fizz":
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

**Note:**

- Indentation is extremely important in Python since that's the way blocks are grouped.

Answer (score 2):

```
def fizz_count(words_list):
    return len([word for word in words_list if word == 'fizz'])
```

OR

```
def fizz_count(words_list):
    return words_list.count('fizz')
```

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, really, but give it a thought when you advance your Python (which you can start now).

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the return statement after the for loop

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == "fizz":
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Comment: Now you've got it. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not used to this syntax editor and I failed the indentation when I submitted the solution at first :P

Answer (score 2):

put your return at the end of your for loop. so it would be:

```
    for item in x:
        if item == "fizz":
            count+= 1
    return count
```

Comment: Hint: Use leading four-space indentation to format code blocks.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist thanks I'm new and I wasn't sure, i got it now though!

Comment: NP. [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) is really fun and useful (it's used here, git, and other places). There's also a wonderful utility called [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) that can do all kinds of things with it. I encourage you to learn it!

Answer (score 1):

return is part of the if block.  Do not return until the for block has finished:

```
def fizz_count(x):
count = 0
for item in x:
    if item == "fizz":
        count = count + 1
return count
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that the assignment requires you to write an explicit for loop for counting, but this kind of error due to misindentation is exactly why I personally prefer using functional idioms in python.
You can implement this like:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    return len([item for item in x if item == "fizz"])
```